# Dynamic mass hosting using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure an apache server using mod_wsgi for dynamic mass hosting. Each user will have it's own instance of a python application located in /mnt/data/www/domains/[user_name] and there will be a vhost.map telling me which domain maps to each user's directory (the directory will have the same name as the user). What i do not know is how to write the WSGIScriptAliasMatch line so that it also takes the path from the vhost.map file.
What i want to do is something like this: I can have on my server different domains like www.virgilbalibanu.com or virgil.balibanu.com and flaviu.balibanu.com where each domain would belog to another user, the user name having no neccesary connection to the domain name. I want to do this beacuse a user, wehn he makes an acoount receives something like virgil.mydomain.com but if he has his own domain he can change it later to that, for example www.virgilbalibanu.ro, and this way I would only need to chenage the line in the vhost.map file
So far I have something like this:

```
Alias /media/ /mnt/data/www/iitcms/media/
#all media is taken from here

RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

# define the map file
RewriteMap vhost txt:/mnt/data/www/domains/vhost.map

#this does not work either, can;t say why atm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/media/uploads/$1

#---> this I have no ideea how i could do
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^([^/]+) /mnt/data/www/domains/$1/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory "/mnt/data/www/domains">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch ^/mnt/data/www/domains/([^/]+)/apache>
  AllowOverride None 
  Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>

<Directory /mnt/data/www/iitcms/media>
  AllowOverride None
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
  Order allow,deny 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch ^/mnt/data/www/domains/([^/]+)/media/uploads>
  AllowOverride None
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
  Order allow,deny 
  Allow from all 
</DirectoryMatch>
```

I know the part i did with mod_rewrite doesn't work, couldn't really say why not but that's not as important so far, I am curious how could i write the WSGIScriptAliasMatch line so that to accomplish my objective.
I would be very grateful for any help, or any other ideas related to how i can deal with this. Also it would be great if I'd manage to get each site to run in wsgi daemon mode, thou that is not as important.

Thanks,
Virgil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion thread about this at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_frm/thread/2a9905f24c10a967